# Log4j2 Syslog appender(TCP protocol) sending exception stacktrace in multiple lines and showing wrong log levels

Tags: log4j2, syslog

I am using log4j2 and syslog appender. I am using TCP as protocol and Kiwi syslog server. While sending the error messages, the exception stacktrace is being sent over TCP in multiple lines, each line in one one packet. The first line of the stacktrace is shwoing correct log level in Kiwi syslog server, but the subsequent of the same stacktrace is shwoing wrong log level and facility. This is not happening in case of UDP protocol.

```
01-22-2015  10:25:40    Local0.Error    10.74.224.251   1 2015-01-23T00:20:11.473+05:30 ABC-PC - - [mdc@1000 category="com.test.dataSender" exception="" thread="ForkJoinPool-57-worker-1"] [8ef587c9-5605-42d3-88ff-0d865cf6e510]: Failed to add management service instance 'aa', Cause: aa
01-22-2015  10:25:39    Local7.Debug    10.74.224.251   " thread="ForkJoinPool-57-worker-1"] [8ef587c9-5605-42d3-88ff-0d865cf6e510]:  Unknown Host : aa
01-22-2015  10:25:39    Local7.Debug    10.74.224.251      at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:398)
01-22-2015  10:25:39    Local7.Debug    10.74.224.251      at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.work(ForkJoinPool.java:646)
01-22-2015  10:25:39    Local7.Debug    10.74.224.251      at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:784)
01-22-2015  10:25:39    Local7.Debug    10.74.224.251      at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.execTask(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:604)
01-22-2015  10:25:39    Local7.Debug    10.74.224.251      at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:334)
01-22-2015  10:25:39    Local7.Debug    10.74.224.251      at java.util.concurrent.RecursiveTask.exec(RecursiveTask.java:93)
01-22-2015  10:25:39    Local7.Debug    10.74.224.251      at com.test.data.core.mapreduce.MapReduceTask.compute(MapReduceTask.java:26)
01-22-2015  10:25:39    Local7.Debug    10.74.224.251      at com.test.data.core.datasource.DatasourceAdder.map(DatasourceAdder.java:21)
01-22-2015  10:25:39    Local7.Debug    10.74.224.251      at com.test.data.core.datasource.DatasourceAdder.map(DatasourceAdder.java:70)
01-22-2015  10:25:39    Local7.Debug    10.74.224.251      at com.test.data.um.datasource.UMDatasourceService.addDatasources(UMDatasourceService.java:58)
01-22-2015  10:25:39    Local7.Debug    10.74.224.251      at com.test.data.um.datasource.UMDatasourceServiceFacadeImpl.addDatasources(UMDatasourceServiceFacadeImpl.java:211)
01-22-2015  10:25:39    Local7.Debug    10.74.224.251      at com.test.data.um.datasource.UMDatasourceServiceFacadeImpl.discoverDatasources(UMDatasourceServiceFacadeImpl.java:248)
01-22-2015  10:25:39    Local7.Debug    10.74.224.251      at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1048)
01-22-2015  10:25:39    Local7.Debug    10.74.224.251      at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1098)
01-22-2015  10:25:39    Local7.Debug    10.74.224.251      at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1162)
01-22-2015  10:25:39    Local7.Debug    10.74.224.251      at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1246)
01-22-2015  10:25:39    Local7.Debug    10.74.224.251      at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1293)
01-22-2015  10:25:39    Local7.Debug    10.74.224.251      at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:901)
01-22-2015  10:25:39    Local7.Debug    10.74.224.251      at java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
01-22-2015  10:25:39    Local0.Error    10.74.224.251   1 2015-01-23T00:20:11.471+05:30 ABC-PC [OnCommand API Services] - - [mdc@1000 category="com.test.data.um.datasource.UMDatasourceServiceFacadeImpl" exception="java.net.UnknownHostException: aa
```

Another question, regarding `mdc@1000`, what is this? why this is getting printed? I have added `includeMDC=true` in log4j2 config file.

```xml
<Syslog name="syslogAppender" 
        host="${sys:syslog.host}" port="${sys:syslog.port}" protocol="${sys:syslog.protocol}" 
        appName="${serviceName}" enabled="${sys:syslog.enabled}" format="RFC5424" 
        newLine="true" includeMDC="true" mdcId="mdc" ignoreExceptions="true" 
        enterpriseNumber="1000">
   <LoggerFields>
      <KeyValuePair key="thread" value="%t" />
      <KeyValuePair key="category" value="%c" />
      <KeyValuePair key="exception" value="%ex{full}" />
   </LoggerFields>
</Syslog>
```

Comment: Please some reply to my question.

Comment: How do you know it was Log4j2 that sends the multiple lines as separate packet? Maybe Syslog is treating them as separate?