# log4j CustomConfigurationFactory creating a new log file for every line of a stack trace?

Tags: java, scala, log4j

I have the following CustomConfigurationFactory. However, instead of just logging everything to a single file, names 'api', it seems to be creating a new log file for every line of a stack trace?

```
import com.example.api.{LoggingConfig, SyslogConfig}
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Level
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.builder.api._
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.builder.impl.BuiltConfiguration
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.Plugin
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.{ConfigurationFactory, ConfigurationSource, Order}

@Plugin(name = "CustomConfigurationFactory", category = ConfigurationFactory.CATEGORY)
@Order(50)
class LoggingConfFileConfigurationFactory(loggingConfig: LoggingConfig) extends ConfigurationFactory{


  override def getConfiguration(loggerContext: LoggerContext, source: ConfigurationSource): BuiltConfiguration = {
    getConfiguration(loggerContext, source.toString(), null) 
  }

  override def getConfiguration(loggerContext: LoggerContext, name: String, configLocation: URI): BuiltConfiguration = {
    val builder: ConfigurationBuilder[BuiltConfiguration] = ConfigurationBuilderFactory.newConfigurationBuilder();
    createConfiguration(name, builder);
  }

  override def getSupportedTypes(): Array[String] = {
    Array[String]("*")
  }

  private def createConfiguration(name:String, builder: ConfigurationBuilder[BuiltConfiguration]): BuiltConfiguration = {

    builder.setConfigurationName(name)
    builder.setStatusLevel(Level.ERROR) //internal log4j level of logging

    val consoleAppenderBuilder: AppenderComponentBuilder = builder.newAppender("Stdout", "CONSOLE")
      .addAttribute("target", ConsoleAppender.Target.SYSTEM_OUT)
    consoleAppenderBuilder.add(builder.newLayout("PatternLayout")
      .addAttribute("pattern", "%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"))

    builder.add(consoleAppenderBuilder)

    if(loggingConfig.appenders.contains("Syslog")) {
      builder.add(createSyslogAppender(loggingConfig.syslogConfig, builder))
    }

    val rootLogger = builder.newRootLogger(Level.valueOf(loggingConfig.level))

    for(appender <- loggingConfig.appenders) {
      rootLogger.add(builder.newAppenderRef(appender))
    }

    for(logger <- loggingConfig.loggers) {
      builder.add(builder.newLogger(logger.name, logger.level))
    }

    builder.add(rootLogger)
    builder.build()
  }

  private def createSyslogAppender(syslogConfig: Option[SyslogConfig], builder: ConfigurationBuilder[BuiltConfiguration]) = {

    val config = syslogConfig match {
      case Some(x) => x
      case None => SyslogConfig("syslog-ng", 515, "api", "LOCAL0")
    }

    val messageFormat = builder.newComponent("KeyValuePair")
    messageFormat.addAttribute("key", "class")
    messageFormat.addAttribute("value", "%logger{36}")

    builder.newAppender("Syslog", "Syslog")
      .addAttribute("format", "RFC5424")
      .addAttribute("host",
        loggingConfig.syslogConfig match {
          case Some(x) => x.host
          case None => "syslog-ng"
        })
      .addAttribute("port", config.port)
      .addAttribute("protocol", "TCP")
      .addAttribute("appName", config.appName)
      .addAttribute("includeMDC", "true")
      .addAttribute("mdcId", "mdc")
      .addAttribute("facility", config.facility)
      .addAttribute("newLine", "true")
      .addAttribute("messageId", "Log")
      .addAttribute("id", config.appName)
      .addComponent(
        builder.newComponent("LoggerFields")
          .addComponent(messageFormat)
      )
  }
}
```

Here is the relevant part of my application.conf, which gets injected into the above class as the loggingConfig constructor param:

```
logging = {
  level = "INFO"
  appenders = "Stdout,Syslog"
  syslog = {
    host = "syslog-ng"
    port = 515
    appname = "api"
    facility = "LOCAL0"
  }
```

Here are some of the contents of the /var/log/syslog-ng directory.

```
ls /var/log/syslog-ng/  

java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java                                               
slick.jdbc.Invoker.foreach(Invoker.scala
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java                                    
slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker.foreach(StatementInvoker.scala
api
```

These are the versions of log4j I'm using:

```
"org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-api" % "2.8",
"org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-core" % "2.8",
"com.typesafe.scala-logging" %% "scala-logging" % "3.5.0",
"org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-slf4j-impl" % "2.8"
```

I expect all logs to go into the 'api' file, but instead I'm getting a new file created for every line of a stack trace. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Related:

[Log4j2 Syslog appender(TCP protocol) sending exception stacktrace in multiple line and shwoing wrong log levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28096978/log4j2-syslog-appendertcp-protocol-sending-exception-stacktrace-in-multiple-li?rq=1)

and

[Send log4j2 stack traces over syslog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40486799/send-log4j2-stack-traces-over-syslog?rq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was that line breaks ("\n") are  assumed to be the end of a syslog message when sent over TCP.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40590058/5300930

https://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-413

https://github.com/rsyslog/rsyslog/issues/1165

My workaround was to format stack traces to use something other than line breaks for each line:

I changed this:

```
logger.error(s"Trace: %s".format(t.getStackTrace.mkString("\n")))
```

to this:

```
logger.error(s"Trace: %s".format(t.getStackTrace.mkString(" -> ")))
```